# Python requests json, make the json respons look better

Tags: python, python-requests

How do i make this outcome : 
`[{"id":71346,"username":"CrowZoneMan","uuid":"03f7d47a-fc8e-44c2-9415-1a6aeb6aada1","kills":218,"deaths":382,"joins":569,"leaves":563,"adminlevel":0}]`

Look like this :

```
username =: CrowZoneMan
uuid : 03f7d47a-fc8e-44c2-9415-1a6aeb6aada1
kills : 218
deaths : 382
joins : 569
leaves : 563
adminlevel : 0
```

Basically how do i organize the json response to make it easier to understand.

edit: The second output does not have to look exactly like that, just more organized and easier to use.

Comment: That second thing *isn't* JSON. If you want to display it like that, though, what have you tried?

Comment: `json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)`

Comment: your desired output and the JSON look the same to me

Comment: dump it to yaml I guess?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The seconds thing is not json, and that is the point. i want it to be easier to read when i display it.

Comment: So again, what have you tried?

Comment: @gold_cy Well the first one is the "raw" output i got from the request. I want it to look more organized like the second one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have tried anything yet, i searched around but i couldn't find anything on how to organize the output from the JSON.

Comment: @epiKubuntu, I've already posted solution 7 minutes before/

Comment: @OlvinRoght So will i print it out like this?
```print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)```

Comment: @epiKubuntu, yes

Comment: @OlvinRoght When i do that i just get a syntax error.

Comment: @epiKubuntu, don't forget to ```import json```

Comment: It seems like all you want is to iterate over a list, then print key:value pairs from each dictionary in it. It's hard to believe you can't even get to the *start* of code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post `json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)` but @Olvin already commented that. So this might be what you are looking for

```py
import pprint
x = [{"id":71346,"username":"CrowZoneMan","uuid":"03f7d47a-fc8e-44c2-9415-1a6aeb6aada1","kills":218,"deaths":382,"joins":569,"leaves":563,"adminlevel":0}]
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(x)
```